# I downloaded the desktop 18.04 LTS and it doesn't work?

Tags: boot

I have a windows 10 computer that reaches the wallpaper and then locks. I have been advised to try [this](https://www.pcworld.com/article/2147063/linux-to-the-rescue-how-ubuntu-can-help-a-computer-in-distress.html). A download of ubuntu to a USB.

I loaded the ubuntu-18.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso as directed and plugged it into a USB socket on my bad computer.
The load sequence is set to see USB first and I saw a purple screen with two small icons at the bottom, one oblong and the other a circle with a figure in, this stayed on for about 5 seconds, the screen then went black with the cursor in the top left corner for about 5 seconds then the screen went into standby as if the computer was shutting down but the computer just continued to run.
I have tried this a few times and reloaded the usb stick a few times.
If I look at the stick on this computer it shows all the files in directories and the name of the stick as UBUNTU 18_0.

Any idea what I am doing wrong would be welcome.
Thanks,
Bob

Comment: 12.04 is beyond dead.  But what you downloaded is 18.04, not 12.04.  Chances are what you're seeing is the lagtime with the system loading up 18.04 Desktop into RAM which takes a bunch of time on some systems.  Consider trying Lubuntu instead?  (http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/18.04/release/lubuntu-18.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso) it uses a lighter DE and has less demands on the system but will still give you access to your system, etc. the same as an Ubuntu 18.04 live disk

Comment: A couple things you should know, Ubuntu can't fix hardware problems or it should not be use to fix Windows software problems.  It can be use to maybe clean windows of malware and maybe get your data off of a corrupt windows system.  Windows problem usually best fixed with windows tools like repair disks.  Ubuntu is also a nice operating system if you want a change or try something new.

Answer (score 0):

these two icons prompt you to touch "any" key (e.g. the spacebar) in order to set your language and keyboard layout. If you do nothing the file system will be checked, then it will start. 
Obviously that did not happen. You did not write, what kind of hardware you have, (would be great if you'd provide ALL information and not just tiny bits) but it seems to be something that ubuntu can't cope with. So I'd do the follwing:

1. Start again and touch the keyboard when you see the two icons
2. Select the Language you understand/want
3. Press F6 Function key -> a menu pops up:
   [image: a menu pops up]
4. Select nomodeset by selecting it an hit the "Return"(that means: don't try to load anything, just get it running). A "x" should appear in front of "nomodeset"
5. Press "ESC"
6. Select "Try Ubuntu without installing (safe graphics)

The last point only, because you did not tell us, what kind of hardware you're using.
So it would be great (and fair to those who try to help) to tell us, what hardware you have, how you created that usb stick and specify what happend before you had your window problem....

When you selected that entry something should happen. Describe it - exactly what you see. Do not hesitate to take pictures of your screen and paste them into your question - which you can edit to add more information.... and change your title. Its 18.04  not 12..

(This should've been a comment - but I don'know how insert images into one. )

Comment: Sorry I just gave another answer instead of commenting on yours.

Answer (score 0):

thank you kanehekili.
While I was waiting for an answer I am trying different things and found another thread on here that blamed the video card. I have a spare so I swapped them.
The ubuntu loads up correctly now.
I went back to the site mentioned above and tried to follow the instructions for finding passwords.
It tells me to open a terminal and enter the following

> sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
>   $(lsb_release -sc) universe"
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install chntpw

after a few tries I found the terminal opens with 
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
if I enter the first line nothing happens except the terminal drops a line and opens without the line above if I enter the line again I get

"ERROR need a single repository as argument"

[photo of screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xminH.jpg)

I hope you can make out the photo as it also shows errors for the other two lines?

Comment: Yep, ubuntu is trying to get repository information while you tried to to do the same. That lock will go away... So wait a little bit and you'll be able to add your repository, hoping it will help you to find you little windows bug. <rant> That  is one of many reasons why I haven't touched the windows operation system for a decade </rant>

Comment: I am assuming you are saying that I am asking for the repository twice?

Comment: I am assuming you are saying that I am asking for the repository twice? With that in mind I went and asked again and finished up with        ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe"     the terminal dropped a line and nothing seemed to happen. I did    sudo apt-get update      anyway and got a long list of things happening. When it stopped I added    sudo apt-get install chntpw      and got    reading package lists.......done.  building dependency true     reading state information.....done     E:unable to locate package chntpw

Comment: I ran out of space in the comment? so I will continue here just to say I am moving forward but without a result yet?

Comment: I followed the next line in the instructions on the site mentioned above,    enter into the terminal cd /media/   and press the tab key twice, I just get the terminal drop a line with cd /media/ still there and no alphanumeric label as the text says?

Comment: eh, are you doing this on a live USB? Then you probably have no sudo... By the way. The instruction seems pretty old. Now you call `sudo apt install ...` Make sure the repository still exist. This looks like using a linux distro to "hack" a forgotten windows password. I'll try to replay that stuff on my virtual machine later. I'll let you know, what I've found out...

Comment: Thanks for your time kanehekili.

Comment: Thanks for your time kanehekili. I keep trying to go down a line with 'return' and it posts the bit I am typing. duh. I am trying to fix a windows computer that loads up to the wallpaper but then locks just before all the icons are loaded. I was just going to do a fresh clean back to the windows 10 but don't know the serial number of the windows 10 on the machine. I was advised that this ...https://www.pcworld.com/article/2147063/linux-to-the-rescue-how-ubuntu-can-help-a-computer-in-distress.html      website might help get me the serial number .

Comment: It looks as if it might get the passwords, which I already have, is there any way of getting the serial number of the windows software you know of? I thought the passwords and the serial number might be in the same place. I used this site  https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#3-usb-selection  to download a copy of ubuntu onto a stick and used that.

Comment: It looks as if it might get the passwords, which I already have, is there any way of getting the serial number of the windows software you know of? I thought the passwords and the serial number might be in the same place. I used this site  https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#3-usb-selection  to download a copy of ubuntu onto a stick and used that. no sudo might be why it fails when I try to sudo apt-get install chntpw?